# Bagging with random forest, object not found even with MASS:Boston data set

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to follow along in a textbook example from James et al.'s "An introduction to statistical Learning with Applications in R" and I am running into an error message I don't understand.

```
 library(MASS)
 library(randomForest)
 set.seed(1)
 bag.boston=randomForest(medv~.,data=Boston, subset=train,mtry=13, importance=TRUE)
 yhat.bag = predict(bag.boston,newdata=Boston[-train,])
```

With this last line I get the error message

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'age' not found

Why am I getting this error message and how do I prevent it? I see that a similar question was asked here:
[Error in running randomForest : object not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074597/error-in-running-randomforest-object-not-found)
. but in that case the OP was trying to input a matrix rather than a data frame as their original data set, and anyhow that is at the randomForest call, rather than the predict call.

This person [randomForest in R object not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864307/randomforest-in-r-object-not-found-error) also had a similar problem, but traced it to non ascii characters in their text file, which I am pretty sure is not characteristic of this data set.

Maybe I am supposed to subsstitute the word "data" for "newdata" in the predict function, but that seems to yield really different answers than I see in the text examples.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a copy of that book you're referring to, which has been [published online](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf) by the author and USC.

You left out necessary code to run this code block. In the book that code snippet was from a file / R session that had been broken up between many pages and code blocks and depends on the earlier code being run, such as creating `train`. When the necessary code is included from that book it runs fine. The error you got cannot be reproduced.

```
library(MASS)
library(randomForest)
library(tree)
set.seed(1)
train = sample(1:nrow(Boston), nrow(Boston)/2)

bag.boston=randomForest(medv~.,data=Boston, subset=train,mtry=13, importance=TRUE)
yhat.bag = predict(bag.boston,newdata=Boston[-train,])

summary(yhat.bag)
```

> ```
>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
>   7.965  17.050  21.330  22.700  25.530  48.690
> ```

Comment: Huh. Yeah, works for me now that I restarted everything and ran exactly the code you supplied. Note that the tree.boston line isn't necessary for the function to run.